# How to replace &nbsp; with whitespace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace `'&nbsp;'` in my code with simple whitespaces " ". These things aren't actually the same.

How can I do this?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexnotonfire/htg6qdxo/)

This code won't work.

**HTML**

```
<p>No Space</p>
<p>&nbsp;1 Space</p>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Spaces</p>
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 Spaces</p>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Spaces</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi," "));
    });
});
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Is there a specific reason you need to do this? It's obviously not for UI reasons, as `&nbsp;` is encoded to whitespace by default.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's my specific [reason](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/dYJWqM). Check out the way it's being displayed. Note, that text is identical in both columns, but the only difference is that the first column has '&nbsp;' instead of whitespaces.

Comment: this is working in your fiddle with Chrome... the `&nbsp`s are being replaced with ` ` and each item in the list is showing up as if there was one space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the **source code**, after jQuery replaces NonBreakingSPaces `&nbsp;` with `" "`:

```
<p>No Space</p>
<p> 1 Space</p>
<p>  2 Spaces</p>
<p>   3 Spaces</p>
<p>    4 Spaces</p>
```

so the actual **space** characters **are present!!**.

#### Why than the spaces do not show up in the document?

The main difference between nested spaces or spaces before a literal string character are eaten by the brower it's mainly an old [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) to prevent Inaccurate content spacing created by sloppy editorial, **but not only that**! imagine that all the spaces and newlines that you see inside an unminified (standard) HTML code - showed up in the result! You'd be forced to write oneliners.

So if you're not using a word wrap style `white-space: pre-wrap;` or an element like `<pre>` that will PREserve your literal spaces the browser will clean the rendered content spaces for you.

```html
<pre>
<p>No Space</p>
<p> 1 Space</p>
<p>  2 Spaces</p>
<p>   3 Spaces</p>
<p>    4 Spaces</p>
</pre>
```

Using `pre-wrap` to preserve literally spaces:

```css
body{ white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
<p>No Space</p>
<p> 1 Space</p>
<p>  2 Spaces</p>
<p>   3 Spaces</p>
<p>    4 Spaces</p>
```

Or you'll use exactly what you're trying to remove: `&nbsp;`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap

Comment: That was definitely useful answer! Thank you!

Comment: I found out the interesting thing. There are two columns filled with the text and I use CSS to cut off the long text and at the end of the specific line I add three dots. But that's not about that. The thing is that in both columns I wrote identical text, but in first column I divided it with `nbsp`s and in the second column I just wrote whitespaces instead of `nbsp`s. Check out that they're not the same. [Link](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/dYJWqM)

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko because `words&nbsp;Some` becomes one single word! It's called *Non-breaking-Space* :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, test this by replacing `" "` with `"s"` or some other letter to see how the nbsp is being replaced.

Any number of spaces in paragraph tags only count as one space.

Replace the `<p>` tag with a `<span>`, and you will see your replacement has worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/93jmn65f/

HTML:

```
<p>No Space</p>
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Spaces</span>
    <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;2 Spaces</p>
        <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3 Spaces</p>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;4 Spa     ces</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('p').each(function(){
      $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&nbsp;/gi,"s"));
    });
});
```

Comment: While letters are displayed, the spaces remain invisible.

Comment: Yes, because the paragraph tag represents mutliple spaces as a single space. @Roko C. Buljans answer is much better than mine, read it! Also, try the JFiddle I posted to see the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Regex on the textContent :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var re = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(160), "gi");
  $('p').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this)[0].textContent.replace(re, " "));
  });
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q75geonu/)

Answer (score -1):

What may be happening is that the literal &nbsp; in the javascript is being decoded before the JS is compiled.  One way to cure this would be to put it into a separate .js file instead of inline in the HTML.  Another would be to try representing it as `/&amp;nbsp;/`.

(By the way, I had to enter "&amp;nbsp;" into this textbox to show "&nbsp;" above... and I had to double the &amp;s to illustrate that here.  But I didn't have to do that inside the `code ticks`.  Just an oddity of SO.)

Comment: That's my specific [reason](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/dYJWqM). Check out the way it's being displayed. Note, that text is identical in both columns, but the only difference is that the first column has '&nbsp;' instead of whitespaces. – Alexander Shmatko just now   edit

Comment: in what way would a string literal be "decoded" before the JS is compiled?

Comment: It isn't an oddity of SO. SO allows HTML in your posts, so you need to escape it. But if you format it as code, SO escapes it for you.

Comment: I call that an oddity.

Comment: @pherris: in xhtml if you don't use an explicit cdata container, or if js is inline in an html attribute.